# Getting unexpected error cocoapod install pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I had the pods working fine until I tried to install another pod and started getting a strange error, I have done no updates and was working perfectly until recently.

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Wireless' do
pod 'TapjoySDK', '~> 10.2'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField',
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK',
pod 'DLRadioButton'
end
```

Error message I am getting

```
SyntaxError - /Users/amir/Desktop/Wireless/Podfile:10: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK',


     ^
/Users/amir/Desktop/Wireless/Podfile:10: syntax error, unexpected  ',', ex   pecting keyword_end
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:254:in `eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:254:in `block in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:51:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:251:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:251:in `from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:227:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:176:in `podfile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:109:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:100:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.3/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error description says that it gets an unexpected `,` symbol.

Change your `Podfile` to

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Wireless' do
pod 'TapjoySDK', '~> 10.2'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
pod 'DLRadioButton'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!!! Just out of curiosity, how did this change, since I originally installed the pods with the , symbol?

Comment: Sometimes people write examples on websites just from the mind, not by coping from the working projects. Don't be afraid of reading the error logs. In most cases they seem to be very useful.

Comment: The keyword `end` can be handled after `,` but not another `pod`. As explained here: `syntax error, unexpected  ',', expecting keyword_end`

Answer (score 3):

This is likely the culprit `syntax error, unexpected  ','`.

Remove the `,` from the end of the lines.

For instance:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Wireless' do
pod 'TapjoySDK', '~> 10.2'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
pod 'DLRadioButton'
end
```